# Deriving the structure of a pytorch network

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, tensor

For my use case, I require to be able to take a pytorch module and interpret the sequence of layers in the module so that I can create a “connection” between the layers in some file format. Now let’s say I have a simple module as below

```
class mymodel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_channels):
        super(mymodel, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(input_channels, input_channels)
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.fc(x)
        out += x
        return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    net = mymodel(5)

    for mod in net.modules():
        print(mod)
```

Here the output yields:

```
mymodel(
  (fc): Linear(in_features=5, out_features=5, bias=True)
)
Linear(in_features=5, out_features=5, bias=True)
```

as you can see the information about the plus equals operation or plus operation is not captured as it is not a nnmodule in the forward function. My goal is to be able to create a graph connection from the pytorch module object to say something like this in json :

```
layers {
"fc": {
"inputTensor" : "t0",
"outputTensor": "t1"
}
"addOp" : {
"inputTensor" : "t1",
"outputTensor" : "t2"
}
}
```

The input tensor names are arbitrary but it captures the essence of the graph and the connections between layers.

My question is, is there a way to extract the information from a pytorch object? I was thinking to use the .modules() but then realized that hand written operations are not captured this way as a module. I guess if everything is an nn.module then the .modules() might give me the network layer arrangement. Looking for some help here. I want to be able to know the connections between tensors to create a format as above.

Answer (score 2):

The information you are looking for is not stored in the `nn.Module`, but rather in the `grad_fn` attribute of the output tensor:

```py
model = mymodel(channels)
pred = model(torch.rand((1, channels))
pred.grad_fn  # all the information is in the computation graph of the output tensor
```

It is not trivial to extract this information. You might want to look at [torchviz](https://github.com/szagoruyko/pytorchviz/blob/master/torchviz/dot.py) package that draws a nice graph from the `grad_fn` information.