# How to save model architecture in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I know I can save a model by `torch.save(model.state_dict(), FILE)` or `torch.save(model, FILE)`. But both of them don't save the architecture of model.

So how can we save the architecture of a model in PyTorch like creating a `.pb` file in Tensorflow ? I want to apply different tweaks to my model. Do I have any better way than copying the whole class definition every time and creating a new class if I can't save the architecture of a model?

Comment: What you mean by the architecture? `torch.save(model, FILE)` should work just fine

Comment: I don't think you can save the model architecture that easily. I am only aware of saving the string of `nn.Sequential` models. What solution did you end up finding? Btw, people refer to the architecture as the actual DAG of computation while model usually means the NN + parameters with the given DAG.

Comment: I ended up saving the hyper-parameters in a `.sh` file. So I can train a lot of models without copying the code. Sounds a little stupid but seems to be the easiest way for me. @CharlieParker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://medium.com/udacity-pytorch-challengers/saving-loading-your-model-in-pytorch-741b80daf3c) article to understand how to save the classifier. To make a tweaks to a model, what you can do is create a new model which is a child of the existing model.

```
class newModel( oldModelClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(newModel, self).__init__()
```

With this setup, newModel has all the layers as well as the forward function of `oldModelClass`. If you need to make tweaks, you can define new layers in the `__init__` function and then write a new forward function to define it.

Answer (score 6):

Saving all the parameters (`state_dict`) and all the Modules is not enough, since there are operations that manipulates the tensors, but are only reflected in the actual *code* of the specific implementation (e.g., [`reshape`ing in ResNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926088/runtimeerror-expected-4-dimensional-input-for-4-dimensional-weight-1024-64-3/62928180?noredirect=1#comment111291003_62928180)).

Furthermore, the network might not have a fixed and pre-determined compute graph: You can think of a network that has branching or a loop (recurrence).

Therefore, you must save the actual code.

Alternatively, if there are no branches/loops in the net, you may save the computation graph, see, e.g., [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58254445/1714410).

You should also consider exporting your model using [`onnx`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html) and have a representation that captures both the trained weights as well as the computation graph.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the actual question:

> So how can we save the architecture of a model in PyTorch like creating a .pb file in Tensorflow ?

The answer is: You cannot

> Is there any way to load a trained model without declaring the class definition before ?
> I want the model architecture as well as parameters to be loaded.
>
> no, you have to load the class definition before, this is a python pickling limitation.

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-save-load-torch-models/718/11

Though, there are other options (probably you have already seen most of those) that are listed at this PyTorch post:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html

Answer (score 2):

PyTorch's way of serializing a model for inference is to use `torch.jit` to compile the model to TorchScript.

PyTorch's TorchScript supports more advanced control flows than TensorFlow, and thus the serialization can happen either through tracing (`torch.jit.trace`) or compiling the Python model code (`torch.jit.script`).

Great references:

- Video which explains this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=2awmrMRf0dA
- Documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html

Answer (score 2):

**Export/Load Model in TorchScript Format** is what you are looking for

Another common way to do inference with a trained model is to use TorchScript, an intermediate representation of a PyTorch model that can be run in Python as well as in C++.

**NOTE**: Using the TorchScript format, you will be able to load the exported model and run inference without defining the model class.

```
class TheModelClass(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TheModelClass, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

# Initialize model
model = TheModelClass()
```

Export:

```
model_scripted = torch.jit.script(model) # Export to TorchScript
model_scripted.save('model_scripted.pt') # Save
```

Load [ Works w/o defining model class ]:

```
model = torch.jit.load('model_scripted.pt')
model.eval()
```

[image]

```
       **Model arch in Netron looks like this**
```