# RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [1024, 64, 3, 3], but got input of size [32, 10] instead

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, resnet, torchvision, deep-residual-networks

This line works fine

```
self.conv = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
```

I introduced ResNet18

```
self.conv = ResNet18()

**ResNet Class**

    '''ResNet in PyTorch.

For Pre-activation ResNet, see 'preact_resnet.py'.

Reference:
[1] Kaiming He, Xiangyu Zhang, Shaoqing Ren, Jian Sun
    Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition. arXiv:1512.03385
'''
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class BasicBlock(nn.Module):
    expansion = 1

    def __init__(self, in_planes, planes, stride=1):
        super(BasicBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(
            in_planes, planes, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(planes, planes, kernel_size=3,
                               stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)

        self.shortcut = nn.Sequential()
        if stride != 1 or in_planes != self.expansion*planes:
            self.shortcut = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_planes, self.expansion*planes,
                          kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(self.expansion*planes)
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        out = self.bn2(self.conv2(out))
        out += self.shortcut(x)
        out = F.relu(out)
        return out


class Bottleneck(nn.Module):
    expansion = 4

    def __init__(self, in_planes, planes, stride=1):
        super(Bottleneck, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_planes, planes, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(planes, planes, kernel_size=3,
                               stride=stride, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(planes)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(planes, self.expansion *
                               planes, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(self.expansion*planes)

        self.shortcut = nn.Sequential()
        if stride != 1 or in_planes != self.expansion*planes:
            self.shortcut = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(in_planes, self.expansion*planes,
                          kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(self.expansion*planes)
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        out = F.relu(self.bn2(self.conv2(out)))
        out = self.bn3(self.conv3(out))
        out += self.shortcut(x)
        out = F.relu(out)
        return out


class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, block, num_blocks, num_classes=10):
        super(ResNet, self).__init__()
        self.in_planes = 64

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3,
                               stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.layer1 = self._make_layer(block, 64, num_blocks[0], stride=1)
        self.layer2 = self._make_layer(block, 128, num_blocks[1], stride=2)
        self.layer3 = self._make_layer(block, 256, num_blocks[2], stride=2)
        self.layer4 = self._make_layer(block, 512, num_blocks[3], stride=2)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(512*block.expansion, num_classes)

    def _make_layer(self, block, planes, num_blocks, stride):
        strides = [stride] + [1]*(num_blocks-1)
        layers = []
        for stride in strides:
            layers.append(block(self.in_planes, planes, stride))
            self.in_planes = planes * block.expansion
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = F.relu(self.bn1(self.conv1(x)))
        out = self.layer1(out)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = self.layer3(out)
        out = self.layer4(out)
        out = F.avg_pool2d(out, 4)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.linear(out)
        return out


def ResNet18():
    return ResNet(BasicBlock, [2, 2, 2, 2])


def ResNet34():
    return ResNet(BasicBlock, [3, 4, 6, 3])


def ResNet50():
    return ResNet(Bottleneck, [3, 4, 6, 3])


def ResNet101():
    return ResNet(Bottleneck, [3, 4, 23, 3])


def ResNet152():
    return ResNet(Bottleneck, [3, 8, 36, 3])


def test():
    net = ResNet18()
    y = net(torch.randn(1, 3, 3, 64))
    print(y.size())

# test()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that resnet18 (and most other classification netwroks) are *not* [fully convolutional networks](https://towardsdatascience.com/review-fcn-semantic-segmentation-eb8c9b50d2d1). The last layer of the net is actually a `nn.Linear` layer and therefore you cannot simply replace a convolutional block/layer with a resnet.

Comment: Thank you. I want to use ResNet18 here because i want to extract deep features. Any Idea please?

Comment: @KhawarIslam you can exclude the fully connected layers of the resnet and just use the conv layers.

Comment: @VictorZuanazzi not so fast - the `forward` function of `resnet` has `out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)` you need to edit the **code** of resnet for this to work.

Comment: Instead of using networks for classification, you can use networks that perform segmentation. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html#semantic-segmentation they are fully connected and input and output usually have the same sizes

Comment: @VictorZuanazzi Thanks for your comment. I am doing this task for image compression and in my opinion if I extract code features then my results will be improved.